# Trigo function integral

Tags: integration, trigonometry

How to solve this equation?

$\int (2x \tan x) \mathrm dx + \int (x^2 \sec^2 x)\mathrm d x$

Can I use integration by parts?

Comment: Try differentiating $x^2\tan x$

Comment: ...or use by parts on one of the integrals and see what happens

Comment: the integral $\int 2x\tan(x) dx$ has no solution in the known elementary functions

Comment: for $\int x^2\sec(x)^2dx$ we have the same statement

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That's not the question.

Comment: but it is the real answer this can't be integrated by parts the function have no elementary solutions

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner But you have a **sum** of integrals, which is actually computable by elementary functions (see David Quinn's first comment). Integrate one by parts, and the other will simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the second integral by parts.

$$\int dx \, x^2 \sec^2{x} = x^2 \tan{x} - \int dx \, 2 x \, \tan{x} $$

I hope you can take it from there...

Comment: OK thnk you.I hope it may help...

Comment: @MunawwarahAziz: you hope?  Did you actually look at the solution and compare it to your problem?